# How to refresh vscode.TreeDataProvider based TreeView?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

the TreeView is initially populated and the TreeView instantiated. the 'refresh' button invokes the custom refresh function to gather updated data. This new information is stored in context.globalState()

The `ctmInfrastructureProvider.refresh();` does not update the TreeView. I've added the event listener as well.

```
export class CtmInfrastructureProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<number> {

    private _onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.EventEmitter<number | null> = new vscode.EventEmitter<number | null>();
    readonly onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.Event<number | null> = this._onDidChangeTreeData.event;
.
.
.
    constructor(private context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
        let ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp: any = context.globalState.get('ctmInfrastructureCache');
        this.refresh();
    }
.
.
.
}
```

Here are my refresh functions:

```
let ctmInfrastructureRefreshEntry = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
        'ctm.infrastructure.refreshEntry',
        async () => {           
ctmInfrastructureDicsovery = discoverCtmInfrastructure();                     context.globalState.update('ctmInfrastructureCache',JSON.parse(ctmInfrastructureDicsovery));
ctmInfrastructureProvider.refresh();
        }
    );
    context.subscriptions.push(ctmInfrastructureRefreshEntry);
```

The TreeDataProvider refresh()

```
    refresh(offset?: number): void {
            this.parseTree();
    }
```

```
    private parseTree(): void {
        this.text = this.ctmInfrastructureCache;
        this.tree = json.parseTree(this.ctmInfrastructureCache);
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to trigger the change event yet:

```
    refresh(offset?: number): void {
            this.parseTree();
        this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire();
    }
```

### Update

Actually, I use a slightly different approach than that from the tree demo:

```
import { TreeDataProvider, TreeItem, EventEmitter, TextDocument, ProviderResult, Event } from "vscode";
import { AntlrFacade } from "../backend/facade";

export class AntlrTreeDataProvider<T> implements TreeDataProvider<T> {
    protected currentFile: string | undefined;

    private changeEvent = new EventEmitter<void>();

    public constructor(protected backend: AntlrFacade) { }

    public get onDidChangeTreeData(): Event<void> {
        return this.changeEvent.event;
    }

    public refresh(document: TextDocument | undefined): void {
        if (document && document.languageId === "antlr" && document.uri.scheme === "file") {
            this.currentFile = document.fileName;
        } else {
            this.currentFile = undefined;
        }
        this.changeEvent.fire();
    }

    public getTreeItem(element: T): TreeItem {
        return element;
    }

    public getChildren(_element?: T): ProviderResult<T[]> {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

Taken from my VS Code extension: https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/frontend/AntlrTreeDataProvider.ts. As you can see I use `EventEmitter` instead, which does not require a parameter for the `fire()` event.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Here's the issue I'm running into next: Cannot find name '_onDidChangeTreeData'. Did you mean the instance member 'this._onDidChangeTreeData When I use "this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire();" I get: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
index.d.ts(1569, 14): An argument for 'data' was not provided.

Comment: Still not working, even though I'm using the MS VS Code TreeView sample as a basis and added:  
```refresh(offset?: number): void {
  this.parseTree();
  if (offset) {
   this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(offset);
  } else {
   this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(undefined);
  }

 }
```

Comment: the refresh itself is working. I've assign some static value and the new tree gets populated. However, my updated data is stored in "context.globalState.get('ctmInfrastructureCache')". When I want to use this in the function I'm getting: "Property 'globalState' does not exist on type 'SuiteFunction'" - How do I access the globalState in the refresh function of my class?

Comment: Please finish this question first and then open a new one with that follow up question.

Answer (score 0):

The refresh is working if the new data is being provided by the function.
Example:

```
    refresh(offset?: number, context?: vscode.ExtensionContext): void {
        this.ctmInfrastructureCache = "some data";
        this.parseTree();
        if (offset) {
            this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(offset);
        } else {
            this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(undefined);
        }

    }
```